# Large cardinals: Every weakly compact cardinal has the extension property.

Tags: set-theory

I'm starting to study the basic theory of Large cardinals with Jech's book Set Theory. I'm having struggles understanding the details of the proof that if a cardinal $\kappa$ has the extension property (that is, for every $U\subset V_\kappa$ there exists a transitive set $M$ (with $\kappa\in M$) and $U'\subset M$ such that $(V_\kappa,\in, U)\prec (M,\in ,U')$ ) then it is $\Pi^1_1$-indescribable. That is, given any $\Pi^1_1-$ formula $\forall X\,\varphi(X)$ and $U\subset V_\kappa$ if $\langle V_\kappa, \in, U\rangle \vDash \forall X\,\varphi(X)$ then there exists $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\langle V_\alpha, \in, U\cap V_\alpha \rangle \vDash \forall X\,\varphi(X)$. For this purpouse Jech takes an arbitrary $\Pi^1_1$ formula and an arbitrary $U\subset V_\kappa$ and making use of the extension property proves that there exists $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\langle V_\alpha, \in, U\cap V_\alpha \rangle \vDash \forall X\,\varphi(X)$. Here is a screenshot of the proof:

[image]

Regarding my doubts they are itemized in the following lines:

1. Given $\forall X\varphi(X)$ a $\Pi^1_1$ formula if 
   ($\forall\, X\subset V_\kappa$) $\langle V_\kappa,\in, U\rangle\vDash \varphi(X)$ why $\langle M,\in, U'\rangle \vDash (\forall\, X\subset V_\kappa$) $\langle V_\kappa,\in, U'\cap V_\kappa\rangle\vDash \varphi(X)$? It is because the formula "$\forall\, X\subset V_\kappa$ $\langle V_\kappa,\in, U\rangle\vDash \varphi(X)$" is an absolute? If it is the case, why is absolute?
2. $V^M_\kappa=V_\kappa$: I know that if $\kappa$ is inaccesible then $V_\kappa=L_\kappa$ and since $\kappa\in M$ and $\alpha\mapsto L_\alpha$ is an absolute for transive models then $V^M_\kappa=V_\kappa$. Is it right?
3. If $\langle M,\in, U'\rangle \vDash (\forall\, X\subset V_\kappa$) $\langle V_\kappa,\in, U'\cap V_\kappa\rangle\vDash \varphi(X)$ why $\langle M,\in, U'\rangle \vDash \exists \alpha\; (\forall\, X\subset V_\alpha$) $\langle V_\kappa,\in, U'\cap V_\alpha\rangle\vDash \varphi(X)$
4. The last hence: Why the last line implies $\langle V_\alpha, \in , V_\alpha\cap U\rangle \vDash \sigma$?

Please, Is someone willing to explain me the details under the previous items?

Best,

Cesare

Comment: Why would you think that $V_\kappa = L_\kappa$ for inaccessible $\kappa$? That doesn't hold.

Comment: Oh, I hoped so... Thank you for the appointment @Stefan. Then, why the universe $V_\kappa$ is an absolute?

Comment: I have actually troubles understanding your post. Maybe you could try to phrase your questions more carefully? For example: The model $(M; \in, U')$ depends on the subset $U \subseteq V_\kappa$ that we've chosen. But you seem to fix a single $(M; \in, U')$ throughout your whole post.

Comment: I have already modified my question. If it still being unclear please tell me :)

Comment: It's still a bit messy, but now I seem to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I'm so sorry... If it would be helpfull I could take a screenshot of Jech's proof.

Comment: @Stefan Regarding to item 2, is the following reasoning right? Suppouse that $\phi(\alpha,x)$ is the formula which states "$x\in V_\alpha$". Since $V^{V_\beta}_\alpha$ for all $\beta>\alpha$ then $\phi(\alpha,x)^{V_\kappa}\leftrightarrow \phi(\alpha,x)$ for every $\alpha<\kappa$ and $x\in V_\kappa$. Now, we have the following equivalences:

$x\in V_\kappa$ iff $ \exists\,\alpha\in \kappa \phi(\alpha,x)$ iff $\exists\,\alpha\in \kappa \phi(\alpha,x)^{V_\kappa}$ iff $\exists\,\alpha\in \kappa \phi(\alpha,x)^M$ iff $x\in V_\kappa^M$.

The third equivalence is by elementarity.

Comment: Since the rank function is absolute between transitive models $N$ of $\operatorname{ZFC-}$, we have $V_\alpha^N = V_\alpha \cap N$. In our case $V_\kappa \subseteq M$ (since $V_\kappa$ is a substructure) and hence $V_\kappa^M = V_\kappa$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Stefan ! Regarding to the other items I think I have an explanation for $1$ and $4$ but I'm still stuck with the third one... Concerning to 1, $(\forall\, X\subset V_\kappa)\langle V_\kappa, \in, X\rangle \vDash \varphi(X)$ is equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ formula because $\langle V_\kappa, \in, U\rangle \vDash \varphi(X)$ is $\Delta_0$ so it is a downward closed formula. 

On the other hand if $\langle V_\kappa, \in , U\rangle \vDash \langle V_\alpha, \in U\cap V_\alpha \rangle \vDash\forall X\,\varphi(X)$

Comment: then $\langle V_\alpha, \in, U\cap V_\alpha \rangle \vDash\forall X\,\varphi(X)$ because of absoluteness of the satisfaction.

Comment: Looks fine to me. The third one is trivial, but you stated it wrong: $(M; in, U') \models \exists \alpha \forall X \subseteq V_\alpha \colon (V_\alpha; \in, U') \models \phi(X)$ (namely, $\alpha = \kappa$, because $U' \cap V_\kappa = U$ and absoluteness of the modeling relation). Now pull this back to $(V_\kappa; \in, U)$. Then $(V_\kappa; \in , U) \models \exists \alpha \forall X \subseteq V_\alpha \colon (V_\alpha; \in, U)$. By absolutness, $V$ models this as well.

Comment: Thank you another time @Stefan! My last trivial question is the following (Sorry for any inconvenience....) To give a sense to the second statment it is necessary to see that $V_\kappa\in M$. But this is true because for all $\alpha<\kappa$ we have $V_\alpha=V^M_\alpha$ and $V_\alpha\in V^M_\kappa=V_\kappa\subset M$ so $V_\alpha \in M$ for every $\alpha<\kappa$. Using replacement and union we conclude $V_\kappa \in M$. Is this right?

Comment: As I said in a previous comment: Since $M$ is a model of $\operatorname{ZFC-}$ and $\kappa \in M$, we have $V^M_\kappa = V_\kappa \cap M \in M$. Now use $V_\kappa \subseteq M$ to obtain $V_\kappa^M = V_\kappa$.